# JSF page won't reload if I write to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: jsf, bytearrayoutputstream

Basically, I have a JSF page that displays a count and a "download" button. What I want to have happen is when the button is clicked a text file is created and downloaded and the page's count gets incremented.

When I click the CommandButton the bean.download method gets called, text gets written to a ByteArrayOutputStream and is downloaded. But the count does not refresh (page isn't reloaded).

If I don't call the method to write to the ByteArrayOutputStream, then the page does get updated and shows the new count value.

The JSF page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>

    <h:form id="mainForm">
        <h:outputText id="countLbl" value="Download Count = #{bean.count}" />

        <br />

        <h:commandButton value="Do Download" action="#{bean.download}"/>
    </h:form>


</h:body>
</html>
```

The Session bean: Bean

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private int count;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        count = 0;
    }

    public String download() {
        count++;
        try {
            doDownload();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void doDownload() throws IOException, ServletException {

        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            String line = "dummy text";
            baos.write(line.getBytes());
            baos.close();

            sendReport(baos.toByteArray());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public static void sendReport(byte[] bs) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext
                .getResponse();

        response.reset();
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "no-store, no-cache, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=\"down.csv\"");
        response.setContentLength(bs.length);

        ServletOutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        os.write(bs);

        os.close();

        facesContext.responseComplete();

    }

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the server can only send one response per request, try using ajax. I'm haven't used JSF very much but that might help. When you make a request the server can either send the download back, or the refreshed page. With ajax you can have a request be made to update the count, separate from the download request.

It looks like by saying response complete you cancel the page from being loaded, which you are correct by doing, because if you didn't the user would download part of the page with his file.

If you have a javascript function that makes an ajax call to refresh the counter when you click download, that might work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice rubixibuc. That makes sense to me what you said about the server only being able to send back one response. But I'm still stuck as to how to get around this. How could I have a javascript function make an ajax call to refresh the counter when I click download?

Comment: You can use the `onclick` attribute of the download button to trigger an ajax call. So when you click the button it sends an ajax request to the server (ajax works almost exactly the same as any other request, but happens out of sync with the page load) and load the content into the page, usually inside a `<div>`. The jQuery library has a method that does this. http://api.jquery.com/load/ You will have to create a separate page that just returns the counter.

Comment: The JSF framework provides built in tools for this with the ajax tag, but I don't have a lot of experience with them.  Either way will work the same way, although the JSF tag will be less messy if you know how to use it. I recommend trying it with JSF.

Comment: Thanks for your help rubixibuc. I got around the problem by adding  onclick="setTimeout('history.go(0)', 1000);"   to the commandButton to reload the page after one second. Not the best solution but it works.
Cheers
Stephen